# Printing sheets of labels in SSRS 2008 based on data in a table and specific quantities per label

Tags: printing, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to come up with a form in SSRS 2008 that prints labels based on information stored in a table or tables. So far I have been unsuccessful in my online searching. How do I tell SSRS that I want the KitOrder.QuantityCommitted quantity of labels to print for each item? (each item has it's own quantity) I will likely be printing labels for 20-30 items at a time. In case it's helpful to know, there are 18 blank labels per sheet.

edited 10/01/15
Sorry, I played around with with the example you gave and wasn't able to get my report to work. I am not an expert with SSRS.
 I have 2 tables I am using to get the info I need for the labels and only need the columns listed below the table names at this point.

```
KitOrder        INNER JOIN      Item
KitOrderNumber                ItemNumber
Quantity                      ItemDescription
```

I am using KitOrderNumber from a dropdown box - IN(@KitOrderNumber) - as my Parameter. The ItemNumber and ItemDescription print on the label. Would there be some custom code I could use that would return 3 labels when KitOrder.Quantity = 3 instead of just 1 label?

Edited 10/05/15 - I was finally able to get my report to work as needed. Thanks so much for your help. The sqlfiddle was quite helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate when people suggest this when it's not necessary but I think this is one of the times that you'll need to manipulate your data in SQL before the report.

I can't think of an easy way to do it with SSRS that doesn't involve a lot of code.

You create a temp table with your possible quantities then cross join your table to create a separate record for each product based on the number in your Quantity field.

```
;WITH Quantities AS (
SELECT 1 AS Num
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 + Num
FROM Quantities
WHERE Num <=  30
)

Select * from Products 
CROSS JOIN Quantities 
WHERE Num <= Quantity
```

This assumes that your data is in a table called **Products**.

If you have a query, you can SELECT your fields INTO a #Temp table and use that in the Select statement.

For the report, you can set the Columns peoperty on the Report to use as many columns as your label sheet has.

[image]

Here's an SQLFiddle I made that you can play with:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb413/2